# OneDrive using high CPU while syncing Photos collection

Tags: data-synchronization, photos.app, office-365, icloud, microsoft-sharepoint

I recently signed up for a Microsoft 365 account, with OneDrive — my plan is to move essentially all my data into the OneDrive folder on macOS (currently using 11.2.3) so it is continuously backed up. So for it has worked mostly very well - except for my Photos.app data. I moved `~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary` to my OneDrive folder, and now OneDrive is constantly syncing metadata files in that bundle related to its database (*e.g.* `psi.sqlite`, `mediaanalysis.db`, `*.ithmb`) and they are not small - some several hundred MB. I have the bandwidth at home, that is not the issue (although it may become a problem…) - the real issue is my MacBook Pro now almost constantly sounds like I have an airplane taxiing next to me. Looking in `Activity Monitor` I see that the **OneDrive** and **distnoted** are often using 100+% CPU, causing the fans to run at top speed near-constantly.

So — is there any way to keep Photos background processes from constantly updating my Photos Library metadata, and/or get OneDrive to dial down the intense CPU usage? I don't want to have to remove my photos from Photos.app, but I may have find another solution if this doesn't work out.

Comment: check for the photoslibraryd process in activity monitor. It e.g. does the face detection when the photos library is closed. It then writes the info into the database and that's probably triggering the continuous upload.

Comment: @X_841 is there anything that can be done to stop/lessen this?

Comment: Photos should use iCloud for synchronisation. You will have trouble using anything else.  If you want to synchronise your photos with OneDrive get them out of Photos.